# Magento - How to check if email entered during login is registered with the website?

Tags: magento

I'm trying to tell the user which of their email address or password entered during login was wrong instead of the default "Invalid email or password" error.

I went to the relevant controller file:

.../app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/accountcontroller.php

and changed the code from line 141 to:

```
catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
     switch ($e->getCode()) {
          case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD:
                if(Zend_Validate::is($login['username'], 'EmailAddress'))
                    $message = $this->__('Wrong password.');
                else
                    $message = $this->__('That email address was not found.');
                    //$message = $e->getMessage();
break;
```

I used Zend_Validate::is() from the forgotPasswordPostAction() function in the same file to check if the email was registered or not. But it doesn't work during login. I always get the 'Wrong password' message even if the email is not registered.

Is it because I'm using Zend_Validate::is() wrong? What would be the correct function to check if the email is registered or not?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey @shishir, wouldn't this be a security vulnerability though?

Comment: well, the client wants this feature. What's the security vulnerability? Phishing attacks?

Comment: Famous last words :)  Well they can automate attempts to discover valid customer usernames, not necessarily a gigantic hole in and of itself, but probably a best practice to keep that error message in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The admin-user has an authenticate_before event, the customer does not.

there is no event you can hook in. What you might do, and I think it is a bad idea, is to extend the Mage_Customer_AccountController overwrite the loginPostAction and change the

`case Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::EXCEPTION_INVALID_EMAIL_OR_PASSWORD:`

at this point you have the `$session` you can `$session->getCustomer()->loadByEmail($NEWCUSTOMER, $login['username'])`

if `empty($NEWCUSTOMER->getData())` then the email is wrong.

But helping the cracker to know wether he attacks the right username is a bad idea!

Comment: Thanks! It worked with the following small changes:


`$NEWCUSTOMER = $session->getCustomer()->loadByEmail($login['username']);
       $CustData = $NEWCUSTOMER->getData();
       if(empty($CustData))
`